# I need to create a web page and create a checkbox named important or no

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngroute

I need to create a web page and create a checkbox named important or not when user will click on important then data should be stored in the database accordingly. The project which I have to extend ( https://gitlab.com/mariusz.jarocki/pwa2019 ) is written using Node JS and MongoDB at the backend side and AngularJS at the frontend side.

Can you evaluate this task? Is this difficult or easy?

Comment: Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Be aware of school policy.

Answer (score 0):

In the grand scheme of things, the task you are describing is relatively easy. I can't speak to how difficult the task is for you specifically, though. The fact that you are asking the question might indicate that it is a difficult task for you.

Creating a web page with a form is simple, then you need to have the form submit a POST request that the Node.js server handles. Make sure the web page includes the checkbox status in the request. The server then needs a route for that specific request that adds or modifies a document in the DB.

Comment: I am sorry I can ask really simple questions but is that written in code? I am a beginner. Also, do you know some kind of tutorial on internet for this one? I have 10 days to complete this task.

Comment: I mean like step-by-step guidance

Comment: Yes, this will all be written in code. There are multiple components that you will need to find tutorials for, I don't have the time to do that research for you. The code for the database logic will need to happen in the js/rest.js file, and you will need to modify one of the HTML pages and their associated JS scripts.

Comment: It seems like this is a university project, so I'd recommend finding help on-campus and from your professor or TA. Are there lecture notes or textbooks that are part of the course?

Comment: I have little time for this...how much it would cost to order this project to someone with explanations? How do you think?